# BASH: How to set a function parameter uniquely ... prior to calling that function ... within the bash script ... (not using command line parameters)

Tags: bash

Please assist me in understanding how to setup a bash function with a parameter which can be unique each time the function is called (like C for example).

```
myString = "string"

myFunction (parameter-1) {


}


myFunction(myString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell functions take *positional parameters* in an analogous way to shell scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash

myString="string"

myfunc () {
  echo "$1"
}

myfunc "$myString"
```

Comment: I'd told the OP as much in [their previous (deleted) question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2258802?noredirect=1), not sure what to make of their response.

Comment: I needed to see this example on syntax ... Thanks to both of you!